# lazy.js and xml stream parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to parse through a kml file lazily with the xml stream module and running into a lack of relevant examples. Here's my code so far.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var xmlStream = require('xml-stream');
var lazy = require('lazy.js')

var stream = fs.createReadStream('./Sindh.kml');

var xml = new xmlStream(stream);

var onlyEvents = function(e) {
    if (e && e._events) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

lazy(xml).filter(onlyEvents).take(20).each(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log('\n');
});

//xml.preserve('Polygon', true);
//xml.on('endElement: Polygon', function(poly) {
//  var coordString =  poly.outerBoundaryIs.LinearRing.coordinates.$children.join().trim();


  //console.log('\n\n');
//})
```

So, the idea is to duplicate the behavior of the commented out text by filtering the output from the event emitter on the endElement events. I'm getting output here by running the code, I just don't know quite what I'm looking at or where to go from here.

I'm new to streams and lazy.js so apologies if this is a total noob question. Perhaps I'm just not understanding the objects that I'm getting out from the loop.

Comment: This one is tricky because the `xml-stream` library appears to expose something *stream-like*, which offers a slightly different interface to your everyday `stream.Readable` in Node. Lazy currently doesn't offer a way to wrap arbitrary sources as sequences yet. However, that is something I'm going to add in the near future. I will revisit this question when that is available.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  So I guess for now my options are to write a custom sequence to parse the xml like you did in your json example, or write an xml stream module that more strictly adheres to the stream.Readable interface.

If I go the latter route, I should expect each output from lazy to be like an on.data event, correct?

Answer (score 2):

So, yesterday I published version 0.3.2 of Lazy.js, which includes a method called [`createWrapper`](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/docs/#Lazy-createWrapper). From the docs:

> Defines a wrapper for custom StreamLikeSequences. This is useful if
>   you want a way to handle a stream of events as a sequence, but you
>   can't use Lazy's existing interface (i.e., you're wrapping an object
>   from a library with its own custom events).

Don't count on this method being there in this exact form (or even with this exact name) indefinitely; it's just a preliminary sketch of what might end up ultimately in Lazy 1.0. But as it currently exists, here's an example of how you could use it for your purposes w/ the `xml-stream` library, using the [first example KML file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml) from Google's [KML tutorial](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut) (I have no idea if this is the "KML" you're using; but it should illustrate how this works regardless):

```
var fs        = require('fs'),
    XmlStream = require('xml-stream'),
    Lazy      = require('./lazy.node');

// Here we are wrapping an XML stream as defined by xml-stream. We're defining
// our wrapper so that it takes the stream as the first argument, and the
// selector to scan for as the second.
var wrapper = Lazy.createWrapper(function(source, selector) {
  // Within this wrapper function, 'this' is bound to the sequence being created.
  var sequence = this;

  // The xml-stream library emits the event 'endElement:x' when it encounters
  // an <x> element in the document.
  source.on('endElement:' + selector, function(node) {
    // Calling 'emit' makes this data part of the sequence.
    sequence.emit(node);
  });
});

// We can now use the factory we just defined to create a new sequence from an
// XML stream.
var stream = fs.createReadStream('KML_Samples.kml');
var xml = new XmlStream(stream);
var sequence = wrapper(xml, 'Placemark');

// This sequence can be used just like any other, with all of the same helper
// methods we know and love.
sequence.skip(5).take(5).pluck('name').each(function(placemarkName) {
  console.log(placemarkName);
});
```

Output:

```
Tessellated
Untessellated
Absolute
Absolute Extruded
Relative
```

Comment: Nice!  Will try this very soon. I think this will be a good concept for an addition.  As I've been researching npm modules, I've been noticing the stream-like "pattern" quite a bit, especially with parsers.